# How to reduce items in sub arrays based on the index?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce, sub-array

examples:

```
let a1 = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]] //-> [5,7,9]
let a2 = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]] //-> [12,15,18]
let a3 = [[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,6],[4,5,6,7]] //-> [10,14,18,22]
```

I thought I can do this easily but now I can't think straight anymore. :-)

thank you.

Comment: it is not clear how you calculate the outputs. Please explain the input-output conversion.

Comment: @AdamNyx, it seems to be a sum for all the parallel indices. For example, with `a1`, `[1+4,2+5,3+6]`

Comment: you add e.g. a2[0][1] + a2[1][1] + a2[2][1] . hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce the array and map new arrays with sums.

```js
const
    add = array => array.reduce((a, b) => a.map((v, i) => v + b[i])),
    a1 = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]],
    a2 = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]],
    a3 = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6, 7]];    
     
console.log(...add(a1)); // [5, 7, 9] 
console.log(...add(a2)); // [12, 15, 18]
console.log(...add(a3)); // [10, 14, 18, 22]
```

Comment: perfect! thank you. I was so close to a similar solution but I screwed up the logic with mapping.